# How to understand a strange memory address shown in Gdb?

Tags: c, memory, gdb

I am debugging a memory issue with gdb. Gdb gives this error info:

```
runtime error: member access within misaligned address 0x0000006d20f4 for type 'struct deque', which requires 8 byte alignment
0x0000006d20f4: note: pointer points here
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
              ^
```

Question: How does the displayed address

```
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

corresponds to "0x0000006d20f4"?

Comment: It seems not an address but the memory contents.

Comment: Please read the line "note: pointer ***points here***" again. What's displayed is not an address or a pointer, it's the data where some pointer in your code is pointing at.

Comment: The `^` is in a textual 'diagram' showing that the address is pointing 4 bytes from an aligned address.

Comment: If the structure is something like, for example, `struct deque { struct node *head, *tail; };`, the memory contents assigned to the structure is address.

Comment: Which platform do you use? X86 does not require aligned objects AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read in the message itself, the memory address is `0x0000006d20f4` and the value you have highlighted are the contents of that memory location.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.... the pointer points to an address that is multiple of four, but not multiple of eight, so in my opinion, the pointer is pointing to the beginning of the shown block:

```
runtime error: member access within misaligned address 0x0000006d20f4 for type 'struct deque', which requires 8 byte alignment
0x0000006d20f4: note: pointer points here
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  ^  this is actually where the pointer is pointing.
              ^ this is actually address 0x0000006d20f8, which should be correctly  8byte aligned.  Probably where the pointer should be pointing.
```

Should it be possible to check `struct deque` definition, and determine that you are not wrong and it doesn't require to be eight byte aligned?  Have you mangled 32bit architecture definitions with 64bit architecture systems? Please, post the code, not your idea of what can be happening.  You think you are correct, so it is very difficult, from your ideas, to see where is your mistake.  Where did you get the memory to store the `struct deque` object?